# Grails 2 - Using external configuration in tests

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-2.0, integration-testing

I am not able to access configurations properites from **grails-app/conf/Config.groovy** in my Unit Tests and Integration Tests.

The properties does not exist in **grailsApplication.config** object

Using Grails 2.5.1 and IntelliJ IDEA 14

What's the best practice to configure my Unit Tests and Integration Tests with Grails 2?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

For unit tests: 
this is normal behavior, since this is an external dependency and you should not be relying on it, but stubbing it.  UnitTestMixin provides a `config` variable within your unit test, that you can use to stub the values, i.e. `config.myValue = xx`

For integration test: `grailsApplication.config` (just inject `grailsApplication` in you test) should be accessible as usual. You can change the config values, but do not forget to clean up (i.e. restore to original values) after the test.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

IntelliJ > File menu > Project Structure > Modules

Add **grails-app/conf** folder to **Test Source Folders**

**Solution 2:**

Create a separated config file for running tests.

Put a Config.groovy file in **test/unit** folder and another Config.groovy file in **test/integration** folder.

The properties will be loaded into **grailsApplication.config** object